# lastrowid returning None in sqlite3 in python 3

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to fix a problem I'm having in retrieving the last insert id from a query in SQLite3 using Python. 
Here's a sample of my code:

```
import sqlite3

# Setup our SQLite Database
conn = sqlite3.connect('value_serve.db')
conn.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1") # Enable Foreign Keys
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create table for Categories
conn.executescript('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Category;')
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE    Category (
                id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                category        CHAR(132),
                description     TEXT,
                parent_id       INT,
                FOREIGN KEY     (parent_id) REFERENCES Category (id)
                );''')

conn.execute("INSERT INTO Category (category, parent_id) VALUES ('Food', NULL)")
food_category = cursor.lastrowid
conn.execute("INSERT INTO Category (category, parent_id) VALUES ('Beverage', NULL)")
beverage_category = cursor.lastrowid
...
conn.commit()  # Commit to Database
```

No matter what I do, when I try to get the value of 'food_category' I get a return value of 'None'.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `lastrowid` value is set *per cursor*, and only visible to that cursor.

You need to execute your query *on the cursor that executed the query* to get the last row id. You are asking an arbitrary cursor, one that never actually is used to execute the query for a last row id, but that cursor can't know that value.

If you actually execute the query on the `cursor` object, it works:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Category (category, parent_id) VALUES ('Food', NULL)")
food_category = cursor.lastrowid
```

The `connection.execute()` function creates a new (local) cursor for that query and the last row id is only visible on that local cursor. That cursor *is* returned when you use `connection.execute()`, so you could get the same value from that return value:

```
cursor_used = conn.execute("INSERT INTO Category (category, parent_id) VALUES ('Food', NULL)")
food_category = cursor_used.lastrowid
```